# How to handle json files for terraform deployment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am a new in terraform and using below terraform template to create Azure App service plan, App service and App insight together

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.98"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.6"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features { }
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "appService-app_insights" {
  
  name                      ="${var.prefix}-${var.App_Insights}"
  location                = var.Location
  resource_group_name     = var.ResourceGroup
  application_type          = "web" # Node.JS ,java
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice" {
name                    ="${var.prefix}-${var.appservice_name}"
location                = var.Location
resource_group_name     = var.ResourceGroup
app_service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
https_only              = true
site_config {
              linux_fx_version = "NODE|10.14"
            }
app_settings =  {                  
                  #  "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
                  "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = azurerm_application_insights.appService-app_insights.instrumentation_key
                }
depends_on = [
                azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan,
                azurerm_application_insights.appService-app_insights
             ]
}


# create the AppService Plan for the App Service hosting our website
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                      ="${var.prefix}-${var.app_service_plan_name}"
  location                = var.Location
  resource_group_name     = var.ResourceGroup
  kind                      ="linux"
  reserved                  = true
  sku                 {
                        tier = "Standard" # 
                        size = "S1"
                    }
}
```

I am generating a variable.tf file at runtime which is quite simple in this case

```
variable "ResourceGroup" {
  default = "TerraRG"
}

variable "Location" {
  default = "westeurope"
}

variable "app_service_plan_name" {
  default = "terra-asp"
}

variable "appservice_name" {
  default = "terra-app"
}

variable "prefix" {
  default = "pre"
}

variable "App_Insights" {
  default = "terra-ai"
}
```

Everything working good till here.
No I am trying to extend my infra and I want to go with multiple App + App Service Plan + App Insight which might look like below Json

```
{
     "_comment": "Web App Config",
     "webapps": [
         {
             "Appservice": "app1",
             "Appserviceplan": "asp1",
             "InstrumentationKey": "abc"
         },
         {
             "Appservice": "app2",
             "Appserviceplan": "asp2",
             "InstrumentationKey": "def"
         },
         {
             "Appservice": "app3",
             "Appserviceplan": "asp2",
             "InstrumentationKey": "def"
         }
     ]
 }
```

How can I target such a resource creation.
Should I think on creating App Service Plan First and App Insight and then should plan creating Apps. What could be a better approach for this scenario.

Comment: Would the JSON be assigned to an existing variable or to a new variable? Where does that go in the current code, in `azurerm_app_service`?

Comment: If the json can be used directly during plan or apply could be the best. App service has the dependency with app service plan and app Insight. I am sure the tf file needs to be adjusted accordingly, but how is the question.

Comment: If I understand the question and based on the JSON key-value pairs, I would say you should look into using `for_each`. :)

Comment: Hey, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Your answer helps. I need to take it further targeting separate app insight per app.

Answer (score 1):

**Since `app1`,`app2`,`app3` are not globally unique i have tried with different name.**

[image]

**I have tried with app service name `testapprahuluni12345`,`testapp12346`and `testapp12347`.**

***main.tf***

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.98"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features { }
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "appService-app_insights" {
  
  name                      ="${var.prefix}-${var.App_Insights}"
  location                = var.Location
  resource_group_name     = var.ResourceGroup
  application_type          = "web" # Node.JS ,java
}


resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {  
  count = length(var.app_service_plan_name)
  name                      = var.app_service_plan_name[count.index]
  location                = var.Location
  resource_group_name     = var.ResourceGroup
  kind                      ="linux"
  reserved                  = true
  sku                 {
                        tier = "Standard" # 
                        size = "S1"
                    }
}

# create the AppService Plan for the App Service hosting our website
resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice" {
count = length(var.app_names)
name                    = var.app_names[count.index]
location                = var.Location
resource_group_name     = var.ResourceGroup
app_service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan[count.index].id
https_only              = true
site_config {
              linux_fx_version = "NODE|10.14"
            }
app_settings =  {                  
                  #  "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
                  "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = azurerm_application_insights.appService-app_insights.instrumentation_key
                }
depends_on = [
                azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan,
                azurerm_application_insights.appService-app_insights
             ]
}
```

***variable.tf***

```
variable "ResourceGroup" {
  default = "v-XXXXX--ree"
}

variable "Location" {
  default = "West US 2"
}

/*variable "app_service_plan_name" {
  default = "terra-asp"
}

variable "appservice_name" {
  default = "terra-app"
}
*/
variable "prefix" {
  default = "pre"
}

variable "App_Insights" {
  default = "terra-ai"
}

variable "app_names" {
  description = "App Service Names"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["testapprahuluni12345", "testapp12346", "testapp12347"]
}

variable "app_service_plan_name" {
  description = "App Service Plan Name"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["asp1", "asp2", "asp2"]
}
```

***OutPut--***

[image]
[image]