# Azure Application Gateway zone redundant with instance count set to 1

Tags: azure-application-gateway

Configuring an Azure Application Gateway (v2 standard) with zone redundancy (West Europe (Zone 1, 2, 3)) with instance count set to 1 is allowed. How is this possible?

To my knowledge, you should have at least the instance count set to 3 when you select all 3 zones of your region.

What I assume will be happening, either:

1. Will it enforce a minimum count of three behind the scenes if you specify an instance count fewer than three [like App services?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/how-to-zone-redundancy#requirements). And will I pay 3x the amount 'behind the scenes' too?

Or:

2. will it just fallback this single instance to another region in case of a zone disaster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if you set your instance count to 1 and and select all 3 zones of your region it will create 3 instances behind the scene ie one in all 3 zone.
- Since the platform spreads VMs across three zones and you need to account for at least the failure of one zone but if you specify your instance count more than 3 it will count based on this formula : `(zone/zone-1)*workload instance count= Total number of instance will create behind the scene`.

If a capacity larger than three is specified and the number of instances is divisible by three, the instances will be spread evenly.Otherwise, instance counts beyond 3*N will get spread across the remaining one or two zones

Let's take an example ,if your typical peak workload requires four instances, you should provision six instances: (3/2 * 4 instances) = 6 instances.

> And will I pay 3x the amount 'behind the scenes' too.

It will not cost 3x amount. it will cost based on licence you have choosen for zone redundant. Like **Premium v2 or Premium v3**

Comment: thanks. Just to make it more clear, could you provide a sample in a scenario where you set the instance count to 2 (with 3 zones), will it also create 3 instances in total (1 for each zone)? Just like setting the instance count to 1?

Comment: And with instance count to 2, will it spread out the capacity (2 instances = 20 capacity units, which means around 6.66 capacity units (20/3) for each zone? Would that mean that i can only effectively use 6.66 capacity units since only 1 zone will be active?

Comment: You can not set the instance count as 2 using portal. You have use some IAC tool like ARM or Terraform code to set count=2 for instance.

Comment: Like wise you can refer for reference [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733176/how-to-handle-json-files-for-terraform-deployment/71766714#71766714) how i have created a 3 App service plan for a App Service using count from terraform.

Comment: I can set the instance count just fine through the portal (under configuration). But that wasn't my follow up question.